# Objective C webservice request works with http:// but not https://

Tags: objective-c, web-services, https

Any suggestions? The code works perfectly with http but not https://. I wonder if it's the port. The certificate is valid. I get a "server pretending to be another server" error.

```
NSString *post=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"strEmail=%@&strPassword=%@", [self.txtUsername text], [self.txtPassword text]];
    NSLog(@"PostData%@", post);

//      NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dipinkrishna.com/jsonlogin.php"]; // does work
        NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dev.myrdcm.com/felipe.asmx?op=GetSignIn”];// does not work
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-fore-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        NSLog(@"%@",request);
        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSHTTPURLResponse * response = nil;
        NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection  sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Comment: check this [use-https-certificate-handling-to-protect-your-ios-app](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-https-certificate-handling-to-protect-your-ios-app/)

Answer (score 0):

If you get a "server pretending to be another server" error, then certificate is not valid. I have opened yours url in browser and see that certificate is expired.